# Java: adding quantity for a shoping list

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to learning java and have decided to test myself a little.

I have set myself the task of making some sort a shopping basket, a bit like you have on amazon.

I have done all the code like variables, however i don't know how to make it so the user can choose how much of each item they want.

**Here is an exaple of my code**

```
   double oranges;
   double apples;
   double grapes;
   oranges = 0.12;
   apples = 0.16;
   grapes = 0.28;

    //oranges
   System.out.print("Oranges ");
   System.out.print("£");
   System.out.print(oranges);
   System.out.println();

   ///apples
   System.out.print("Apples ");
   System.out.print("£");
   System.out.print(apples);
   System.out.println();

   //grapes
   System.out.print("Grapes ");
   System.out.print("£");
   System.out.print(grapes);
   System.out.println();
```

**Console:**

```
Oranges £0.12
Apples £0.16
Grapes £0.28
```

So does anyone know or point me into the directions of, how i can add a quantity option so the user can choose how much of each item they want.

I would prefer a youtube video as it is easier to understand.

Thankyou for you help,

Steve

Comment: *I would prefer a youtube video as it is easier to understand* what you need is a Java tutorial.

Comment: Look for the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class, using `System.in` as the input (i.e. the keyboard).

Comment: Hello Steve, I'd recommend you use your book to start with the basics. If you don't have a book, then see http://www.mindview.net/Books/TIJ/. People don't tend to provide youtube videos to resolve people's problems on stack overflow. There's always a lot of people ready to help you but you really need to be more precise without needing to make assumptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned above, look into the Scanner Class, this allows you to take user input and manipulate it :)

you would make an int quantity and then ask the user how many they want of a certain product and assign this to the quantity :)

then its simple multiplication :D

another note, about your code, when you have the separate print lines

"

```
System.out.print("Oranges ");
System.out.print("£");
System.out.print(oranges);
System.out.println();"
```

you can combine these together by using " + " in between like so

```
System.out.print("Oranges " + "£" + oranges);
System.out.println();
```

there's a way to also put the next return space in the next sentence you want to write which will follow the console print you have of

`Oranges £0.12`

see if you can find it yourself :D

Regards
Jordan.A

Answer (score 0):

Try switch with a do while loop, keep on asking for some fruits, break out for desired input :

```
do
{
//accept fruit item say input
switch(input)
{
case 1:
// adding stuff
// other cases
}

}
while(input!=something);
```